# Determinants with 9 unknowns

Tags: matrices

Given:
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    18x & 6r & 6u \\
    3y+12x & s+4r &  v+4u \\    
    3z & t & w \\
    \end{vmatrix} =144
$$

I need to calculate:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    u & v &  w \\
    r & s & t \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

What I did so far:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    3x & r & u \\
    3y & s &  v \\  
    3z & t & w \\
    \end{vmatrix}
=24
$$
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x & r & u \\
    y & s &  v \\  
    z & t & w \\
    \end{vmatrix} = 8
$$

Comment: Expand the second determinant along a row of a column. You can't simplify further than this second determinant

Comment: This is false, @Bernard. You can simplify all the way to the desired determinant.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof: You misunderstood what I meant: once you've factored out the second determinant, you have to calculate it. This second determinant can't be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can divide a column by a common factor, if you also divide the determinant value by the common factor. In your case, divide the first column and $24$ by $3$.
2. The determinant of the transposed matrix is identical to the determinant of the matrix. After doing step 1, transpose your matrix; you will see the desired row vectors appear.
3. Switching two rows (or two columns, for that matter) changes the sign of the determinant.

Following those three steps yields the desired result.

Comment: -8 then?

that's nice that you can learn so much from one question

Comment: yea -8 is the answer